# Epson ePOS2 printer ignores connection timeout

Tags: printing, android-bluetooth, epson, epos

I try to print to an Epson bluetooth printer, using their ePOS android SDK (I use the v.2.11.0)

Printing works, but I need to reduce the connection timeout.

I call the connect function like this:

```
mPrinter.connect("BT:00:01:...", 3000);
```

However, the library ignores the value I pass for timeout. Whatever I pass, it takes around 35 seconds to fail if the printer is not reachable.

The documentation specifies that

> timeout :Specifies the maximum time (in milliseconds) to wait for communication with the printer to be established.

So I guess it should work.

Do anyone have an idea, or a way to make the timeout work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm in the same boat using TCP connectivity.  The Java SDK code passes the timeout on to the native driver, which apparently doesn't honor it.